# Xcode Workspace Build Error Sandbox: rsync(1900) deny(1) file-read-data

Tags: xcode, build-error, google-ad-manager

Forgive me for whoever sees this -- I am a new developer and cannot understand what I am missing here. When I build my Xcode workspace for my iPhone which includes ads from AdMob I get this single error:

Sandbox: rsync(1900) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/philiplattanzio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TigerRun-gexhklhksmplmfagqcwbsfjmflme/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Headers

I believe I have the appropriate frameworks installed. I am not sure how to resolve this.

I reinstalled pods, and google swift package manager. I updated the privacy policy on AdMob (Not sure if this has an effect)

Answer (score 20):

Check that ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING is disabled in the project's build settings.

Xcode 15 beta build issues - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731041?answerId=755722022#755722022

Answer (score 15):

Tested in Xcode 15.1[image]

search for ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING in your build setting turn it to NO.

Comment: ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = NO but not works for me. XCode 15.2

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct but incomplete.

1. Set **User Script Sandboxing** to **No** under Project > Build Settings > Build Options.
2. Set **User Script Sandboxing** to **No** under Target > Build Settings > Build Options.
3. From the menu bar, select **Product > Clean Build Folder**.
4. Quit Xcode.
5. In Terminal, run `gem update --system`.
6. Still in Terminal, run `sudo gem install cocoapods`.
7. Finally, run `pod install --repo-update`.

All should work correctly now.